# How to find frames per second of any video file?

Tags: video, framerate

Is there any simple way to find the fps of a video in ubuntu? In windows I use Gspot to find out all the information about a video file. But in ubuntu I find it very difficult to find out this basic information. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not possible, because not all video files have a "fps" (because VFR encoding exists).

Comment: VFR videos still have an average frame rate - whether or not this is useful depends on the application.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This will tell you the framerate if it's not variable framerate:

```
ffmpeg -i filename
```

Sample output with filename obscured:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'somerandom.mkv':
  Duration: 01:16:10.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 720x344 [PAR 1:1 DAR 90:43], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
```

```
ffmpeg -i filename 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p"
```

Someone edited with one that didn't quite work the way I wanted.  It's referenced [here](https://superuser.com/questions/84631/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-frames-in-a-video-on-the-linux-command-line)
Additional edit...If you want the tbr value this sed line works

```
sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) tbr.*/\1/p"
```

Comment: I needed to use tb instead of fp in the one-liner. Seems not all video files report fps but all autput something like tbr tbc which has the same value.

Comment: valid, but the one-liner from the edit output-ed the tbc value not the tbr value in this particular set of output.  something to consider on why i changed it...I'ld rather it fail in a really noticeable way than a way that isn't noticed at all.

Comment: I think `sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) tbr.*/\1/p` misses `"` in the end, no?

Comment: ffmpeg is not deprecated, avconv came from a branch of ffmpeg and to avoid confusion for those using the ffmpeg alternative the fake branch was marked as deprecated to let those users know that the version they were using was changing.  your comment is misleading and could cause users to waste time researching this

Comment: What if it is variable frame rate?

Comment: It specifies VBR in the output.

Comment:  For both constant and variable bit-rate see my solution.

Comment: `ffmpeg` output is not meant to be machine parsed. Use `ffprobe` instead which is meant for this type of usage and you won't need `sed`. See some of the answers for this questions or [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration).

Answer (score 58):

```sh
ffprobe -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate infile
```

Result:

```
2997/100
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer in that it gives the EXACT frame rate (in the example 24000/1001 = 23.976023976)

Comment: sometimes i get `0/0` depending on the format

Comment: Depending on what you want, this either works or doesn't. It reports the framerate of the encoding, but not the actual framerate of the video. For example, a 30fps video encoded into 60fps will report 60fps but will still be 30fps in actual output.

Comment: This didn't work if the video stream is not the first stream, you will get 0/0 if it looks at an audio stream.  I will edit to put `-select_streams V:0`, which will select the first moving video stream.

Comment: @SamWatkins's complement is important. Without it, the command given output `0/0`.

Comment: Not sure about Linux but Windows was expecting `-i` before the `infile` parameter. The command would be `ffprobe ..... -i infile`

Comment:  ¡¡¡¡WRONG!!!  This is the encoder frame-rate, not the video frame-rate. They could match, bun not necessarily! See my solution for the correct answer.

Comment: I noticed that r_frame_rate can return misleading numbers! avg_frame_rate was much more correct.

Comment: From a video/codec point-of-view, how are these 2 numbers determined? Like why is it 2997 by 100 and not 299.7/10, etc.

Comment: This solution also doesn't work in situations where there are 2 (?) video streams. For some videos I get this result: 

```
30/1

30/1
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is a python function based on Steven Penny's answer using ffprobe that gives exact frame rate

```
ffprobe 'Upstream Color 2013 1080p x264.mkv' -v 0 -select_streams v -print_format flat -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate
```

```py
import sys
import os
import subprocess
def get_frame_rate(filename):
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        sys.stderr.write("ERROR: filename %r was not found!" % (filename,))
        return -1         
    out = subprocess.check_output(["ffprobe",filename,"-v","0","-select_streams","v","-print_format","flat","-show_entries","stream=r_frame_rate"])
    rate = out.split('=')[1].strip()[1:-1].split('/')
    if len(rate)==1:
        return float(rate[0])
    if len(rate)==2:
        return float(rate[0])/float(rate[1])
    return -1
```

Comment: `rate = out.decode("utf-8").split('"')[1].split('/')` would be better: It handles the case of multiple video streams. Also, I needed to turn the subprocess output into a string with decode.

Comment: I noticed that r_frame_rate can return misleading numbers! avg_frame_rate was much more correct.

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve the **average frame-rate**, given as a fraction:

> fraction=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "${input}")

Then divide it by rounding to the **nearest integer**:

> python -c "print (round(${fraction}))"

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to command line, is looking at the properties of your file via context menu in Nautilus (graphical file manager). For audio/video files you get an additional tab there with extra informations.

Answer (score 2):

This is a python script to do this using mplayer, in case anyone is interested. It is used `path/to/script path/to/movie_name1 path/to/movie/name2` etc

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
import re
import sys

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{2}.\d{3}) fps')
for moviePath in sys.argv[1:]:
    mplayerOutput = subprocess.Popen(("mplayer", "-identify", "-frames", "0", "o-ao", "null", moviePath), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    fps = pattern.search(mplayerOutput).groups()[0]
    print fps
```

Comment: This is not really exhaustive. For example, your regex will not match videos with `120 fps`, and it will also fail on `25 fps`. Also, you need to escape the `.`. So, use: `(\d+(\.\d+)?) fps`

Comment: Well, this is very outdated now anyway. Nowadays just one plays it in MPV and preses `i`,

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `exiftool` to get info of any file type...
For example with command `exiftool file.swf` I can know the framerate of any swf file, something I cannot achieve with `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 1):

Uses the stats [script](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#stats) bundled by default with MPV. So just play the file with MPV and press `i`. A bunch of statistics including framerate will appear.

Comment: Also works in VLC: Tools > Codec Information.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffprobe <media> 2>&1| grep ",* fps" | cut -d "," -f 5 | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Comment: explain what it will do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the target file, Properties, Audio/Video but you will not get the exact framerate. To get a precise framerate you can install MediaInfo.

Comment: This depends on the Desktop Environment one uses, (if any at all!)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this... you can of course use input arg as the path ;)

```
import numpy as np
import os
import subprocess

def getFramerate():
    con = "ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 D:\\Uni\\Seminar\\leecher\\Ninja\\stream1.mp4"

    proc = subprocess.Popen(con, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    framerateString = str(proc.stdout.read())[2:-5]
    a = int(framerateString.split('/')[0])
    b = int(framerateString.split('/')[1])
    return int(np.round(np.divide(a,b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
framerate=$(( $(ffprobe -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate "$1" | sed 's#/# / #g') ))
```

^ this will return the exact frame rate, and do the maths on it, to give you the final exact frame rate (it will convert `25.000/1` to `25`, for example)

No need for Python (requires a Bash-like shell)

Answer (score 0):

```
$fps = exec("ffprobe -v error -select_streams v -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate input.mkv");
$fps = round(strstr($fps, '/' , true) / substr (strstr($fps, '/'), 1 ), 2);
```

Output Example: `29.97` or `59.94`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the framerate with [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) cli too.

```
mediainfo "filename.mov" "--inform=Video;%FrameRate%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Code to Get a Few things including frames per second (fps), number of frames, height, width.

```
def get_video_info(filename):
#r_frame_rate is "the lowest framerate with which all timestamps can be 
#represented accurately (it is the least common multiple(LCM) of all framerates in the stream)."
result = subprocess.run(
    [
        "ffprobe",
        "-v",
        "error",
        "-select_streams",
        "v:0",
        "-show_entries",
        "stream=avg_frame_rate,r_frame_rate,nb_frames,width,height",
        filename,
    ],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
)
ffprobe_out = str(result.stdout, 'utf-8')
print(ffprobe_out)
r_frame_rate = int(ffprobe_out.split('r_frame_rate=')[1].split('\n')[0].split('/')[0])
avg_frame_rate = int(ffprobe_out.split('avg_frame_rate=')[1].split('\n')[0].split('/')[0])
nb_frames = int(ffprobe_out.split('nb_frames=')[1].split('\n')[0])
height = int(ffprobe_out.split('height=')[1].split('\n')[0])
width = int(ffprobe_out.split('width=')[1].split('\n')[0])
return (r_frame_rate, avg_frame_rate, nb_frames, height, width)
```