# How to obtain frame rate of video as a fraction?

Tags: avconv

I am attempting to determine the exact frame rate of an H.264-encoded video. Using `avprobe`, I can obtain the following information:

```
avprobe version 11-6:11-1, Copyright (c) 2007-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Sep 26 2014 14:36:31 with gcc 4.9.1 (Ubuntu 4.9.1-15ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'VID_20150406_175035.mp4':
  Metadata:
...
  Duration: 00:00:17.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 41925 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 3840x2160, 41941 kb/s, PAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 28.42 fps, 90k tbn (default)
...
```

The frame rate is given as **28.42 fps**. However, it doesn't provide the exact fractional value. For example, 29.97 is a decimal approximation of the fractional value `30000/1001`.

How do I obtain this information?

Comment: Incidentally, `kdenlive` provides a couple of extra digits: **28.4167 fps**. Still no fraction, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you're not interested anymore, but for anyone else finding this question through Google, the answer is [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/468003/564297). I'll shamelessly copy and paste the command. Replace "infile" with your filename.

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of csv=p=0 -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate infile
```